# Why do Groovy closures declare a maximum, rather than constant number of parameters

Tags: groovy, closures

When declaring a closure we can query it for the number of accepted parameters using:

```
Closure#getMaximumNumberOfParameters()
```

So for example:

```
def closure = { String param ->
}
println(closure.maximumNumberOfParameters)
```

Will output:

```
1
```

Why does the method declare the number of parameters as a maximum rather than a constant?

In what situation will the return value of this method differ from the actual number of parameters declared in the closure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default parameters?

```
def closure = { String param = 'something' ->
}
```

So you can technically call

```
closure()
```

And

```
closure('something else')
```